# Embedded Tableau graph is not working in wordpress blog?

Tags: wordpress, embed, tableau-api

I have a graph in [public tableau](https://public.tableau.com/views/Metro_population/Household_size_Area?:embed=y&:showTabs=y&:display_count=yes) and try to embed into my wordpress blog . But it looks different  in [wordpress](https://hkhanal.wordpress.com/) and  tooltip also does not appear.  Do you have any suggestion?. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Q: What online blog services is Tableau Public compatible with?](https://www.tableau.com/public/faq)

> There is also a service called www.WordPress.com which lets you get
>   started with a new and free WordPress-based blog, but it is less
>   flexible than the WordPress you download and install yourself. Blogs
>   hosted on Wordpress.com do not take advantage of tools like Tableau
>   that use JavaScript.

So unless you're using Wordpress on your own dedicated server, embedded Tableau visualisations are not guaranteed to work.

An alternative might be to export an image of your visualisation that links to Tableau Public for use in your blog?

Comment: If the answer was useful and relevant to your concern, then please remember to mark it as the accepted answer. :)